# Start MySQL from the command line without losing prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, mysql, batch-file

I'm on Windows 7. I'm trying to run a .bat file where I stop and start MySQL and run some other commands.

However, running `"C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP\binaries\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"` results in starting `mysqld`, which then occupies the prompt, and the other .bat commands are not run.

- I tried using `Start` → mysqld does not start
- `Start /B`  → mysqld does not start
- `CMD /C`  → mysqld just starts in the same window
- `Start /B startMysql.bat` (a seperate bat that starts mysql) → mysqld does not start

I use this to test the commands:

```
@echo  on
CMD /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP\binaries\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"
timeout 2:
PAUSE
```

Comment: Did you try: `start cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP\binaries\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"` The combination is sometimes needed to get things to work right.

Comment: As you can see from my question I tried that, its in the list of things I tried. It just starts mysqld in the same window, losing the option to run other commands

Answer (score 4):

use "start":

c:>`start c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`

Tested alone and inside a .bat; I am on Windows 8.1 but I expected it works on Windows 7 too

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing MYSQL as a service and running `net start mysql` and `net stop mysql`. That doesn't solve the issue, so I will leave this open for someone to answer. Otherwise I will accept this as the answer.